# AngularJS ngStorage $sessionStorage gives access denied in IE only

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

When running on localhost (via Visual Studios) all is well, when moved to staging IE 11 (only, Chrome/FF both work fine) I am getting an Error:

> Error: Access is denied.
>
> at isStorageSupported
>   (http://stage.mySite.com/Scripts/Frameworks/AngularJS/1.13.15/modules/ngStorage.js:53:21)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (http://stage.mySite.com/Scripts/Frameworks/AngularJS/1.13.15/modules/ngStorage.js:74:17)
>   at invoke
>   (http://stage.mySite.com/Scripts/Frameworks/AngularJS/1.13.15/angular.js:4203:7)
>   at enforcedReturnValue
>   (http://stage.mySite.com/Scripts/Frameworks/AngularJS/1.13.15/angular.js:4056:7)
>   at invoke
>   (http://stage.mySite.com/Scripts/Frameworks/AngularJS/1.13.15/angular.js:4203:7)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (http://stage.mySite.com/Scripts/Frameworks/AngularJS/1.13.15/angular.js:4021:13)
>
> at getService (http://stage.mySite.com/Scripts/Frameworks/AngularJS/1.13.15/angular.js:4162:11)
>
> at invoke
>   (http://stage.mySite.com/Scripts/Frameworks/AngularJS/1.13.15/angular.js:4191:9)

(note I have already Googled this problem a number of ways...)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by updating to the latest version of ngStorage (as 8/5/2015)